# SSJS Rows.add when space is in field name

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm attempting to use SSJS to fill a data extension.  It works well, except when targeting a field with a space in it.  The following code is not working:

```
var record = { "Email Address" : "foo@bar.com" }
var de = DataExtension.Init(tableName);
var result = de.Rows.Add(record);
```

It throws the exception: `There was an error Adding the row(s).`

I've read the docs and searched around.  I've also tried wrapping it with square braces.  Open for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should work properly, and there are no problems with using a field with a space in it.

I guess there is a primary key field in the DE and the exception due to the violation of the primary key constraint.

I would go through the adding data and check to see if there are any duplicate values causing the violation.

Comment: I could believe that.  I'll  go back and double check; thanks!